# Why mi code compiles ok in SSE2 but not in ARM(no NEON)?

Tags: c++, g++, stack-overflow, stack-smash

Well, this is the problem: i was trying to compile my altoin in ARM and i get stack smashing error: . Aborted. then, i try to compile exactly the same code but with SSE2 flags in my other linux computer, and it success. if i disable stack protection on the makefile im able to compile. But isnt good idea disable that. I try use older GCC, but nothing, is the same. my question is, why im able to compile in SSE2 instructions but no in ARM?
This is the code that create a warning on the build logs:

```
double GaussianQuad_N(double func(const double), const double a2, const double b2, int NptGQ)
{
    double s = 0.0;
    double x[NptGQ], w[NptGQ];

    gauleg(a2, b2, x, w, NptGQ);
    for (int j = 1 ; j <= NptGQ ; j++)
        s += w[j] * func(x[j]);

    return s;
}
```

i get:

> warning: stack protector not protecting local variables: variable length buffer [-Wstack-protecto ] double GaussianQuad_N(double func(const double)

Comment: `double x[NptGQ], w[NptGQ];` variable length arrays are not standard in C++.

Comment: but why the error is in the definition of the function? any idea how to translate them to standard?

Comment: "i was trying to compile my altoin in ARM" - What *is* an "altoin?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double x[NptGQ], w[NptGQ];` variable length arrays are not standard in C++. Use std:: vector in C++

```
std::vector<double> x(NptGQ), w(NptGQ);
gauleg(a2, b2, x.data(), w.data(), NptGQ);
```

Comment: i go to try this in a second, but why it compiles with no problems in SSE2 instruction set?

Comment: Because Intel and ARM are different CPU architectures.

Comment: ok, im compiling, is a 20000+ lines project, so, in few minutes i aprove your answere or i tell u what happend, thanks for the help

Comment: now i get this error: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Comment: 20000+ lines is a small project, should not take a while for building.

Comment: othe small point, a project thet uses this same function compiles ok in my ARM what can be the problem? i ran out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

Your arrays have `NptGQ` as the size, which means the valid indexes are 0 up to NptGQ-1.  However, your loop goes from 1 up to NptGQ, so the last iteration will be beyond the end of the array.

Running off the end of an array like this causes undefined behavior -- it may work (if nothing important is in the space after the array) or it may crash or otherwise misbehave.

Comment: ok, i go to try this, but why it works on SSE2 instruction set and not in ARM?

Comment: Perhaps with SSE2, there's extra padding involved and the out of range access only hits that padding and not anything important.

Comment: ooooooh man, if this works, you saved my life, i go to try expand by one the pad

Comment: nah, sadly it not work, i do: for (int j = 1 ; j <= NptGQ - 1 ; j++)  but i get : munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer